# How to change font size of part of an item

Tags: beamer

As I mentioned in the title, I would like to change font size of part of the items (*Location*) listed.  tried to reduce the font size using `\small`, but it did not work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
       \item  \textbf{Project 1}, Location
        \item  \textbf{Project 2}, Location
          \begin{itemize}
            \item item 1
            \item item 2
            \item item 3
            \item item 4
         \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate your help. 
Many thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Your example code shows no mention of `\small` or `(Location)`.  In addition, it is not a complete document that can compile.  Please edit.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you post the `MWE` from `\documentclass{...}...\end{document}` as always?

Comment: `{\small Location}`

Comment: Thanks. I just edited it.  Egreg, I already tried it, but it does not change the font. I am using beamer

Comment: What part of your output should be "smaller"?

Comment: Location (after the comma of the first two items)

Comment: @Val: [This code](https://pastebin.com/6Q6kGpVn) produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9vYb.png). It is evident that the second `Location` is smaller than the first, so `{\small Location}` should work. If not, you'll have to supply us with more information as to why that's not happening in your case. This could include a screen shot, your `.log`, a full minimal example that replicates the behaviour. Anything is better than just saying "it doesn't work."

Comment: Werner, I do not know what happened, but now `\small` works properly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns an issue which cannot be reproduced using the code given, even by the OP (see comments re. it now all works).